# Display ProgressBar while image is loading in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to "swap" out a view at runtime? Here's my goal: I want to display an animated, indeterminate `ProgressBar` view until my image is loaded. Is there a way to do this easily, without having to do a bunch of crazy stuff? Is there a way I can get the resource ID of the `ProgressBar` spinner animation and simply reuse that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. I tend to make a `FrameLayout` which contains both an `ImageView` and a `ProgressBar`. In `onCreate()` I do `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and then once the image loads I do:

```
progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In terms of the threading you should as always use `AsyncTask`. This is easily the most complicated part of the process, although still quite manageable. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202158/how-to-display-progress-dialog-before-starting-an-activity-in-android/5202186#5202186) for a full code listing.