# Displaying a ProgressDialog during an HttpRequest

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask, progressdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display progress dialog before starting an activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202158/how-to-display-progress-dialog-before-starting-an-activity-in-android)

this is my `itemDetails extends Activity` class and `onOkClick` is the method. But when I press the ok button i.e call the method no `ProgressDialog` shows up. But the *Toast messages* show correctly.

I tried using `getApplicationContext()` in the Context parameter of the `ProgressDialog.show()` method, but it is not working. Sorry for this naive question.

```
    public void onOkClick(View v){

        ProgressDialog pleaseWait = ProgressDialog.show(itemDetails.this, "Uploading..", "Please wait for a while...", true);

            //...........
            HttpData httpData = HttpRequest.post("http://www.abc.com/accessServer.php", "");
            //...........
            pleaseWaitGallery.dismiss();
        if(HttpPostTesting.storestring.contains("successful")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `AsyncTask` to display a `ProgressDialog` while doing operations in the background.

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202158/how-to-display-progress-dialog-before-starting-an-activity-in-android/5202186#5202186), which contains a full code sample.

With your code, you are actually showing and dismissing the dialog before the system has a chance to draw it.