# Showing progress dialog box while copying files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am working on File Manager kind of application in which while copying files i want to show progress dialog,I tried using AsyncTask but couldn't do it well can anyone please send me some code relevent to the scenario i am working on..

Comment: Where did you get stuck using asynctask?

Comment: use an async task, tell us what problems you had

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display progress dialog before starting an activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202158/how-to-display-progress-dialog-before-starting-an-activity-in-android)