# Custom Dialog - Login - back button?

Tags: android

I'm trying to setup UI where user will have to login first time they use applications. And Custom Dialog seems like a good thing to use as I want main UI to be kind of visible on background.

So, what I did - I created main Activity and use ShowDialog() with onCreateDialog from main activity.

I created 
public class LoginDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener 
and I can control all stuff on dialog just like activity.

Ideally I like to check if user logged in on main activity and if not - show this dialog. Otherwise just go with activity.

On dialog I'd like to log user in and if user clicks back without logging in - I want to detect it and just finish main activity. This is where I have problem.

1. In WinForms I would do ShowDialog() (in C#) and next line executed when dialog closed for any reason. I can't figure out how to do this in Android.
2. I didn't get to it yet, but I want to show progress bar when Login button clicked. This bar will be in Dialog box. Is it possible/doable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect dialog dismissal using [setOnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29). In this method you could also call `MyActivity.this.finish()`.

For showing a `ProgressBar` during the login process, you probably want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202158/how-to-display-progress-dialog-before-starting-an-activity-in-android/5202186#5202186). It shows the basic structure of `AsyncTask` and you can adapt it to use `ProgressBar` instead of `ProgressDialog`.

You would be changing the bar's visibility in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` with `bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

**Edit**

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
});
```

This code should be in your `MyActivity` wherever you create the dialog. You need to check to see if the user is logged in or not, because `onDismiss` will be called whether it's the user or your own code that closes the dialog.

Comment: @Matthew Can you show me example on how to use (and where to use) setOnDismissListener. I can't find example anywhere

Comment: @Matthew. Yes, it does now. I'm slow with all this handlers (new to Java). However, IDE complained at @Override and I don't think dialog.dismiss() needed. I finish activity anyway, so child dialog will be distroyed anyway, correct? When I run it works properly both ways, I'm just not sure if I need those 2 lines

Comment: Generally using @Override is recommended to prevent spelling errors. However I believe @Override for interfaces (like the code above) is only present in Java 6 and above.

Comment: @Matthew. Hah, another issue :) Obviously, onDismiss get's called when screen rotated. So, once I rotate screen while login Dialog displayed - App just shuts down. Is there any way to handle that properly? Or at least prevent screen rotation for Dialog only, not for whole app?

Comment: I found how I can prevent orientation change. Thanks!