# Using AsyncTask for AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

Anybody knows how to put `AlertDialog` in `AsyncTask`? I have application that using WebService. So I have put Ip address in order to start the application. Currently I have to put default IP address and then I change it using `AlertDialog`, so like settings->insert ip. Right now I would like to each time when the application start, the `AlertDialog` will be create first. I think for that solution, I have to use `AsyncTask`. But in the way I implementing it, I have got some problem regarding using `AsyncTask`

Below show when the application without AsyncTask forr ip

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // set the ip address
        ip = "124.23.204.135";

        //asyncTask for updating gamer's information
        new GamerWorker().execute(ip);

        //refreshing GUI
        intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
```

I'm using `AsyncTask` `GamerWorker()` to updating the information from WebService. I also declaring intent for refreshing GUI. Below show when I implemented `AsyncTask` for `AlertDialog`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // set the ip address
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.alertdialog_add_gamer, null);
        // start creating the dialog message
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // get the editText from the dialog's view
                        EditText text = (EditText) dialoglayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.et_gamerIpOrWebAdress);
                        // disable all input views
                        ip = text.getText().toString();

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // cancels the dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        new MyTask(builder).execute();
        //refreshing GUI
        intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
    }
```

And for `AsyncTask` that I have used I declared:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
          private Builder builder;

        public MyTask(Builder builder) {
            this.builder = builder;
          }

          public void onPreExecute() {
             AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
          }

          public Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            return null;
          }

          public void onPostExecute(Void unUsed) {
            new GamerWorker().execute(ip);
          }
        }
```

Actually from `AlertDialog`, I'm following this answer: [How to display progress dialog before starting an activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202158/how-to-display-progress-dialog-before-starting-an-activity-in-android/5202186#5202186) 
My problem is when I put:

```
         //refreshing GUI
        intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
```

in preExecute is not working, but if I put in onCreate, it will get null pointer. Anybody knows how to solve this problem?So that I can use `AlertDialog` when start the application

**EDIT**: I can put the intent in preExecute, just change the intent to `intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadcastService.class);`. But it seems can't solve the problem. The dialog never been created and always got null pointer.Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solve without using `AsyncTask`. So I have just declared in `onCreate()` and then with `If`-statement I put if the ip is null then the  dialog will be shown. If the condition the user has put the Ip it will execute the `AsyncTask` for updating information to `WebService` as  I mentioned before.

```
       ip = "";
        // start creating the dialog message
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // get the editText from the dialog's view
                        EditText text = (EditText) dialoglayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.et_gamerIpOrWebAdress);
                        // disable all input views
                        ip = text.getText().toString();
                        if (!ip.equals(""))
                        {
                            new GamerWorker().execute(ip);

                            //refreshing GUI
                            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadcastService.class);
                        }
                        //clear();
                        //myList.clear();   

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // cancels the dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        if (ip.equals("") && ip.isEmpty())
        {
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
        else
        {
        // set the ip address
            //ip = "123.123.224.133";
            new GamerWorker().execute(ip);
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadcastService.class);
        }
    }
```

If someone has another solution using `AsyncTask`, please let me know. Thanks