# how to set progress bar when recycler view is clicked

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, progressdialog

I have an app which gets data from json and displays it on recycler view
and when each recycler view is clicked it opens a new activity to show full content. all i want to know is how to show a progress dialog befrore the second activity shows thanks.
Here is my code

```
        public CustomViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<FeedItem> feeditem) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.feeditem = feeditem;
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.excerpt);
        this.categories = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categories);
        this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        FeedItem feeditem = this.feeditem.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, ScrollingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("excerpt",feeditem.getExcerpt());
        intent.putExtra("content",feeditem.getContent());
        intent.putExtra("title",feeditem.getTitle());
        Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(intent.putExtra("content",feeditem.getContent()))).toString();
        intent.putExtra("thumbnail",feeditem.getAttachmentUrl());
        this.ctx.startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Comment: Is there a delay before your other activity is shown? Why do you want to show a progress dialog?

Comment: yes there is a delay; the images take time to load so therefore i want the progress dialog to show as images are being rendered @AbhishekJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with it in your second activity. There, you should do all your data loading or heavy processing work in a background thread and update the UI as and when you have the data or processing is completed.

**AsyncTask** is designed to serve exactly this purpose

```
public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  public LoadDataTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
  }

  public void onPreExecute() {
    progress.show();
  }

  public void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    ... load your image here ...
  }

  public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    progress.dismiss();
  }
}
```

`onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` run on the UI thread. So you can update your UI here, like showing the image.

Your second activity should look like this now:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Loading...");
new LoadDataTask(progress).execute();
```

For further help, check these:

- [How to display progress dialog before starting an activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5202186/3857465)
- [AsyncTask | Android Developers](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ved=0ahUKEwjn7a3y6NnRAhVLtI8KHYjBBbAQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNGLaSuxTknRpqLNZwIIM0qNhRQDwA&sig2=V6RebYOiR0adN6pFzI7Grg)